# How to return sibling XElements in a LINQ to XML statement?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

From the following XML input:

```
<root>
  <node name="one" value="1"/>
  <node name="two" value="2"/>
  <node name="three" value="3"/>
  <node name="four" value="4"/>
</root>";
```

I need to use LINQ to XML to produce the following:

```
<root>
  <name content="one"/>
  <value content="1"/>
  <name content="two"/>
  <value content="2"/>
  <name content="three"/>
  <value content="3"/>
  <name content="four"/>
  <value content="4"/>
</root>
```

This code produces the *name* elements, but not the *value* elements.

```
var input = @"
<root>
  <node name=""one"" value=""1""/>
  <node name=""two"" value=""2""/>
  <node name=""three"" value=""3""/>
  <node name=""four"" value=""4""/>
</root>";


var xml = XElement.Parse(input);
var query = new XElement("root",
    from p in xml.Elements("node")
    select new XElement("name",
        new XAttribute("content", p.Attribute("name").Value) /*,

        new XElement("value", new XAttribute("content", p.Attribute("value").Value)) */
        )
    );
```

If I include the *value* XElement (commented out above) inside the last parenthesis then it is a child of the *name* element, but outside the closing parenthesis it no longer has access to **q** (it is outside the query).

It feels like I need to concatenate two XElements together or somehow include them in another collection that doesn't produce any XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could flatten the attributes using the [`Enumerable.SelectMany` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx). In query format this is equivalent to two [`from` clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx):

```
var query = new XElement("root",
    from p in xml.Elements("node")
    from a in p.Attributes()
    select new XElement(a.Name,
        new XAttribute("content", a.Value)
        )
    );
```

To contrast, using the actual `SelectMany` method and writing it fluently would look like this:

```
var query = new XElement("root",
        xml.Elements("node")
           .SelectMany(n => n.Attributes())
           .Select(a => new XElement(a.Name,
                new XAttribute("content", a.Value))));
```

However, I tend to find the query syntax to be clearer in most of `SelectMany` usages and I tend to stick to one format or another, although it's perfectly fine to mix both.

Comment: I see what this is doing. Now to see if I can adapt it to my real code. Took me a minute to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Using your code as starting point. Wrap the pair in an item element and then replace it with its children.

```
        var xml = XElement.Parse(input);
        var result = new XElement("root",
            from p in xml.Elements("node")
            select new XElement("item", 
                        new XElement("name", new XAttribute("content", p.Attribute("name").Value)),
                        new XElement("value", new XAttribute("content", p.Attribute("value").Value))));

        result.Descendants("item").ToList().ForEach(n => n.ReplaceWith(n.Elements()));
```

Comment: Ah, creative. It would be nice if it could be done without the second pass to replace the item with its children . . .

Comment: While @Ahmad's was more elegant, and a better answer for my question as written, I actually used your method because it better worked for my production code.

Comment: @Jim interesting... was there some added flexibility in Hasan's approach? Just curious :)

Comment: @Ahmad Your approach was right. In my actual code, the second element actually had a whole hierarchy of elements and attributes under it. I didn't see a way to adapt your method to support that. Of course I could have been missing something. I'd be happy to put up some more complex sample code if you want to see about finding a more elegant solution.